# SQL Server Agent Job Next Run DateTime Stuck In The Past

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

The job is enabled, the schedule is enabled, the agent service is running, but the job is not running as it is supposed to. Looking in the *Job Activity Monitor*, it shows a `Next Run` that is actually in the past.

Running the job manually will cause the `Next Run` to advance to the correct scheduled time for a new run, but when the time comes, **the job still won't run.**

**How is this odd issue fixed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because you did a mass disable and then re-enable by updating the `enabled` flag in **msdb.dbo.sysjobs** after a massive outage; instead of doing things the right way and using the stored procedure,
`sp_update_job`.

All of the jobs that were enabled one-by-one via the GUI worked fine, it was just those mass enabled that were a problem. Doing a quick **disable** then **enable** resolved all the issues.

See link for further info: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-update-job-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Syntax:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_update_job  @job_name = N'[Your Job's Name HERE]',  
@enabled = 0 --- This disables, set to 1 to enable;
```

**Don't update system tables directly next time.**

Comment: Not the case for us. Jobs were enabled and disabled via UI but still scheduled in the past